# javascript comparing input to an array live search

Tags: javascript

So I'm working on this Zipline for my free code camp and am pretty much done, i'm just trying to implement a search. I have it working ok but have a couple of bugs.

What i'm doing for the search is that i'm creating a new array then i'm filtering it and comparing it to the text input of the user and if its equal then i will push that value onto a new array then display it on the screen.

is there a better way to do this? so that as the user types it is comparing with the list of arrays I have.

Thanks

Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wtj7s6c6/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var img, user, status, channel,
    url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/",
        /*   cb = '?client_id=5j0r5b7qb7kro03fvka3o8kbq262wwm&callback=?',*/
        cb = '?callback=?',
        //create new array from filtered array
        newArray = [],
        userList = ["freecodecamp", "maximilian_dood", "UltraChenTV", "habathcx", "TeamSpooky", "Nuckledu", "medrybw"];

    /*function updateLog(message) {
    $("#log").html($("#log").html() + "<p>" + message + "</p>");
  };*/

    function addOnlineUser(image, username, status) {
        $(".people")
            .append('<li><a href="http://twitch.tv/' + username + '"><img class="picture" src="' + image + '"/></a><span class="username">' + username + '</span><span class="isOnline">&#10004;</span><p class="status">' + status + '</p></li>');
    };

    function addOfflineUser(image, username) {
        if (image != null) $(".people")
            .append('<li><a href="http://twitch.tv/' + username + '"><img class="picture" src="' + image + '"/></a> <span class="username">' + username + '</span><span class="isOffline">!</span></li>');
        else $(".people")
            .append('<li><img class="picture emptypic"/><span class="username">' + username + '</span><span class="isOffline">!</span></li>');
    };

    function clickOnline() {
        userList.forEach(function (name) {
            $.getJSON(url + 'streams/' + name + cb)
                .success(function (data) {
                if (data.stream !== null) {
                    img = data.stream.channel.logo;
                    user = data.stream.channel.display_name;
                    status = data.stream.channel.status;
                    channel = data._links.channel;
                    addOnlineUser(img, user, status);
                }
            });
        });
    };

    function clickOffline() {
        userList.forEach(function (name) {
            $.getJSON(url + 'streams/' + name + cb)
                .success(function (data) {
                if (data.stream === null) {
                    $.getJSON(url + 'users/' + name + cb)
                        .success(function (data2) {
                        img = data2.logo;
                        user = data2.display_name;
                        channel = data2._links.self;
                        addOfflineUser(img, user);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    };

    function clickSearchOff(array) {
        array.forEach(function (name) {
            $.getJSON(url + 'streams/' + name + cb)
                .success(function (data) {
                if (data.stream === null) {
                    $.getJSON(url + 'users/' + name + cb)
                        .success(function (data3) {
                        img = data3.logo;
                        user = data3.display_name;
                        channel = data3._links.self;
                        addOfflineUser(img, user);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    };

    function clickSearchOn(array) {
        array.forEach(function (name) {
            $.getJSON(url + 'streams/' + name + cb)
                .success(function (data4) {
                if (data4.stream !== null) {
                    img = data4.stream.channel.logo;
                    user = data4.stream.channel.display_name;
                    status = data4.stream.channel.status;
                    channel = data4._links.channel;
                    addOnlineUser(img, user, status);
                }
            });
        });
    };

    $(".online").on('click', function () {
        $(".people").empty();
        clickOnline();
    });

    $(".offline").on('click', function () {
        $(".people").empty();
        clickOffline();
    });

    $(".all").on('click', function () {
        $(".people").empty();
        clickOnline();
        clickOffline();
    });

    $(".all").click();

    $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function () {

        var searchTerm = $(this).val();
        searchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
        console.log("Search term:" + searchTerm);
        //empty screen//
        $(".people").empty();

        var newArray = [];


        for (var i = 0; i < userList.length; i++) {
            if (userList[i].indexOf(searchTerm) != -1) {
                newArray.push(userList[i]);

            }
        }



        console.log("New array: " + newArray);
        clickSearchOff(newArray);
        clickSearchOn(newArray);

    });

})
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest (as I may do) implement some kind of buffer on the `keyup` event in order to not always trigger the comparison, only after one or two seconds pass after the last `keyup` trigger:

```
var compareTimeout;
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function () {
    clearTimeout(compareTimeout);
    compareTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        var searchTerm = $(this).val();
        searchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
        console.log("Search term:" + searchTerm);
        //empty screen//
        $(".people").empty();
        var newArray = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < userList.length; i++) {
            if (userList[i].indexOf(searchTerm) != -1) {
                newArray.push(userList[i]);
            }
        }
        console.log("New array: " + newArray);
        clickSearchOff(newArray);
        clickSearchOn(newArray);
    }, 2000);
});
```

This would make the function run only after 2 seconds after the last keyup event, and not every time the user types a letter in the input.